# How can I program a replacement fob for a 2003 Malibu?

Tags: chevrolet, malibu, keyless-entry, fob, program

How do I program a replacement fob for my 2003 Malibu (not remote-start equipped)?

**EDIT:**

I have tried to do the following:  The instructions that came with the fobs said to

1. Sit in the car
2. Shut all doors
3. Put the key in the ignition.
4. Hold the door unlock button on the drivers door.
5. turn the key to the on position
6. turn the key to the off position
7. turn the key to the on position
8. turn the key to the off position
9. release the unlock button on the door.
10. Car is supposed lock and unlock.
11. After that you have to hold the lock and unlock on the fob for 30 seconds.

IT DOES NOT WORK.

I have tried to sit in the car, close door, hold door lock on unlock while I enter the key, pull it out. Enter the key, pull it out, enter the key and release the door unlock button. The door is supposed to chime three times. Then I am supposed to hold the lock and unlock button on the fob for 12 seconds. The door is supposed to chime twice and the fob should be programmed.

I have tried this also and there were no chimes.

I think this product is wrong.  People are telling me to take it to Chevy or a locksmith.  Why do that if you say it works?

Answer (score 1):

You need specialized equipment to break the encryption. The equipment will cost more than simply taking it to a dealer or remote and alarm specialist and having *them* do it. It's not an overly complicated job, but the equipment makes it infeasible.

Comment: Yup, everything I'm seeing shows the 2003 Malibu as not being able to reprogram old or program new remotes. This will need to go to the dealership or a locksmith as you suggest. This sucks. I was able to program the remotes for the 2004 Suburban I used to own. Lost a set of keys, reprogrammed a new fob, then found the old set and had to reprogram it all again, lol.

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your problem. If your not too happy about it, check your local 'Yellow Pages' for a company selling and programming auto keys.

1. Sit in the driver's seat
2. Remove the ignition key from the ignition lock cylinder
3. Close all the doors
4. Press and hold unlock on the door lock switch (on the door)
5. While holding the door lock switch in the unlock position, insert and remove the
   ignition key twice. DO NOT ROTATE THE KEY.. JUST SLIDE IT IN AND BACK
   OUT.
6. Insert the ignition key the third time, leaving the key in the ignition cylinder. DO
   NO TURN KEY
7. Release the door lock switch. You will hear 3 chimes indicating the transmitter
   programming is active.
8. Press and hold the lock and unlock buttons on the keyless entry remote at the
   same time (one remote) for 12 seconds. You will hear two chimes. This indicates the
   transmitter has been programmed.
9. Repeat step 8 for all additional transmitters to be programmed
10. Exit programming by removing the key from the ignition cylinder